# Cookie Consent popup on every site

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I'm trying implementing a cookie consent with this component https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent. The information get shown on the site, but even if you agree it will show again after refresh. I have to fill this events, but I don't know how.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgcCookieConsentService } from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  //keep refs to subscriptions to be able to unsubscribe later
  private popupOpenSubscription: Subscription;
  private popupCloseSubscription: Subscription;
  private initializeSubscription: Subscription;
  private statusChangeSubscription: Subscription;
  private revokeChoiceSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to cookieconsent observables to react to main events
    this.popupOpenSubscription = this.ccService.popupOpen$.subscribe(
      () => {
        // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      });

    this.popupCloseSubscription = this.ccService.popupClose$.subscribe(
      () => {
        // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      });

    this.initializeSubscription = this.ccService.initialize$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcInitializeEvent) => {
        // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      });

    this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
        // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      });

    this.revokeChoiceSubscription = this.ccService.revokeChoice$.subscribe(
      () => {
        // you can use this.ccService.getConfig() to do stuff...
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe to cookieconsent observables to prevent memory leaks
    this.popupOpenSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.popupCloseSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.initializeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.statusChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.revokeChoiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your import that you aren't specifying configuration...

```
import { NgcCookieConsentService } from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
```

You need to pull in the config and specify a domain to get cookies working (and therefore stop pestering people!)

```
import {NgcCookieConsentModule, NgcCookieConsentConfig} from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
```

This is where you specify the domain:

```
const cookieConfig: NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: 'example.com'
  },
  // ...
```

You pass the config in where you get `NgcCookieConsentModule`, i.e.

```
NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig)
```

Comment: :sir can you tell me how to store cookies for Marketing and Personalization?